# Can androgen-insensitive genetic-males get pregnant?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction, pathology, endocrinology

According to the linked report, people with [**androgen insensitivity syndrome**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3043767/I-exist-gray-29-year-old-looks-like-woman-male-genitalia-speaks-rare-intersex-condition.html) appear as male, but have both feminine and masculine outer genitalia.

However, I was not able to find out whether their internal reproductive system is functional, i.e., if these people have a functional uterus.

**Is it possible for such a person to get pregnant?**

Comment: A "bug" is basically an insect or a computer software fault. Use proper terminologies. Please try to put in some basic effort. I could have simply said "no humans do not self-fertilize", but it is important to follow some basic discipline. Since you are a programmer and an active SO user, you would perhaps react the same way if I just ask a question without even attempting to code.

Comment: I specified the pathology in the question according to your linked report. Without mention of a pathology this question is too broad to my opinion. However, feel free to roll back if it doesn't reflect your original question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer**
People with androgen insensitivity syndrome do not have a functional uterus and cannot bear a child.

**Background**
Androgen-insensitive genetic males may develop female genitalia and internal female reproductive organs. However, in both partial androgen insensitivity syndrome (PAIS) and complete androgen insensitivity syndrome (CAIS) the uterus is absent, or is present only in a rudimentary form.

The reason for the absence, or rudimentary form of the uterus is the fact that Mullerian inhibiting substance (MIS), produced by the Sertoli cells of the fetal testes is present. MIS controls the regression of the mullerian ducts, and in its absence in XX females, the mullerian system develops into the uterus, oviducts, and upper vagina. However, in XY individuals with CAIS (and likely also with PAIS), MIS is produced normally by the testes resulting in inhibition of the growth of the uterus and fallopian tubes [(Oakes *et al*., 2008)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19064222).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Oakes *et al., J Pediatr Adolesc Gynecol* (2008); **21**: 305-10](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19064222)</sub>

Comment: @mdperry - you cannot tell by looking who is an XY female, and your comment is misleading. I am not tall, and the two XY females I've known as friends are diminutive and certainly not fashion-model material. They are, in fact, no different from me in appearance, except they can't reproduce, and they are usually on hormone replacement therapy.